# How To define Command and CommandTarget in RibbonMenuButton

Tags: wpf, xaml

Good morning; I my application WPF/C# i use Ribbon Control, i want to define a Cammand and CommandTarget for my RibbonMenuButton.

I have this code but my command don't work :(

```
 <RibbonMenuButton LargeImageSource="Resources/Images/new.png" Label="New" KeyTip="N" >
                    <RibbonMenuButton.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.New}" />
                            <Setter Property="CommandTarget" Value="{Binding ElementName=MyDesigner}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </RibbonMenuButton.ItemContainerStyle>
                </RibbonMenuButton>
```

Can you help me !

Comment: is there any binding error? have you implemented command binding for `ApplicationCommands.New`? you may perhaps give a try with `Value="ApplicationCommands.New"` if rest is in place.

Comment: no binding error... now i change the RibbonMenuButton to RibbonButton and it work perfectly

Comment: it sloved like this :

    <RibbonButton LargeImageSource="Resources/Images/new.png" Label="New" KeyTip="N" Command="{x:static ApplicationCommands.New}" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=MyDesigner}"/>

Comment: Great find! let me add few bits. like a popup menu & tooltip also have a different root as they are hosted in a popup, so they are not able to resolve the binding in a normal fashion. if RibbonButton is a substitute for the the RibbonMenuButton then it is perhaps one of the best solution here. you may post your solution as the answer and let others know how you solve it, happy coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my probleme solved like this:

```
<RibbonTab Header=" File ">
            <RibbonGroup Header="File">

                <RibbonButton  Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.New}" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=MyDesigner}"  LargeImageSource="Resources/Images/new.png" Label="New" KeyTip="N"></RibbonButton>

                <RibbonButton SmallImageSource="Resources/Images/Open-3.png" Label=" Open " Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Open}" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=MyDesigner}"/>
                <RibbonButton SmallImageSource="Resources/Images/Save_black-128.png" Label=" Save " Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Save}" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=MyDesigner}"/>
                <RibbonButton SmallImageSource="Resources/Images/Print-icon.png" Label=" Print " Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Print}" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=MyDesigner}"/>
            </RibbonGroup>
```

i have changed the RibbonMenuButton to RibbonButton(with LargeImageSource to preserve the same presentation with RibbonMenuButton).... The RibbonButton alow to define Command and CommandTarget :)